# Javascript replace \n from a string but ignore any word having \\ while replacing

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a string  "yes\no↵abc"  as input in an HTML text area. 
On performing JSON.stringify, it returns me "yes\no\nabc".
Now I need to display the same content back in a textarea in HTML. To replace the "\n" I get after JSON.stringify (Stringify converts ↵ to \n )  I used the following regex str2.replace(/\n/g, "\n"). 
Now how do I escape the \ I am getting.

I have attached code to below

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var str = document.getElementById("para1").value
      var str2 = JSON.stringify(str);
     document.getElementById("para").innerText = "Stringified text \n" +str2;
     var res = str2.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
     document.getElementById("para2").innerText = "Replaced text \n" + res;
     
    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <body>
    Click the button</p>
    <p id="demo">Demo!</p>
    <textarea id = "para1">
    </textarea>
    <textarea id = "para">
    </textarea>
    <textarea id = "para2">
    </textarea>
    <textarea id = "para4">
    </textarea>
    Click
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    

    </body>
    </html>
```

The input to the text area should be:
yes\no

abc

Comment: Why not just replace "↵" to "\n" directly ?

Comment: In your fiddle, doesn't *para2* contain what you want?

Comment: I believe the problem he's running into is that the yes\no is evaluating to yes  o due to the \no and he only wants the return arrow to perform the newline. Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: if i enter  "yes\no
abc" the output is "yes\
o
abc"

Comment: I want the input and output both look the same that is yes/no in the first line and after 2 line abc should be displayed

Comment: The opposite of stringify is parse, not some regex.. `var res = JSON.parse(str2)`

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to use `encodeURI` / `decodeURI` functions instead.  https://jsfiddle.net/xs6c0odr/

Comment: encodeURI only accepts strings and in my case, I have a JSON object that I need to convert to string and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very specific to what you want and has risk of breaking in other scenarios may be, but takes care of what you want in this case.

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var str = document.getElementById("para1").value
      var str2 = JSON.stringify(str);
     document.getElementById("para").innerText = "Stringified text \n" +str2;
     var res = str2.replace(/(\\\\)/g, "\\ ");
        var res = res.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
        var res = res.replace(/\\ /g, "\\");
     document.getElementById("para2").innerText = "Replaced text \n" + res;
     
    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <body>
    Click the button</p>
    <p id="demo">Demo!</p>
    <textarea id = "para1">
    </textarea>
    <textarea id = "para">
    </textarea>
    <textarea id = "para2">
    </textarea>
    <textarea id = "para4">
    </textarea>
    Click
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    

    </body>
    </html>
```

Let me know if that works. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
var res = str2.replace(/\\na/g, "\n a");
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gvedQY

Comment: using this one gives output "yes\\no\n
 abc" not same as the input.

Comment: stringifying string again causing unwanted escape characters. Did you try
document.getElementById("para").innerText = "Stringified text \n" +str;